# Cannot access a control in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Master page I have:

```
 <a id="loginlink" href="Login.aspx">Login</a>
  <a id="logoutlink" href="Login.aspx">Logout</a>
```

In other page which uses this master page I try this:

```
  Page.Master.FindControl("loginlink").Visible = false;
```

This is similar code provided in a Microsoft page. But I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HousingSurvey.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not controls yet, just a markup. To make them server-side controls, add `runat="server"`:

```
<a id="loginlink" href="Login.aspx" runat="server">Login</a>
<a id="logoutlink" href="Login.aspx" runat="server">Logout</a>
```

Comment: This is what I was guessing. So other pages only have access to server controls?

Comment: There is no way to access HTML tags?

Comment: @SNash no, only server controls

Comment: Yes. In the code behind you cannot access any tags. Only server-side controls.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: This is in some way part of the power of .NET, but also the source of many misunderstandings, mostly because webforms is in some way "raping" the web process to make it look statefull.

Answer (score 0):

Strong typing here would be better. That way if the name of the control changes, you'll get a compilation error rather than runtime. Fail early.

Master Page

```
<a id="loginlink" href="Login.aspx" runat="server">Login</a>
<a id="logoutlink" href="Login.aspx" runat="server">Logout</a>
```

Content Page

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/SourcePage.master" %>
```

Code behind

```
Master.loginlink.Visible = false;
```